# How to convert 1000000 to 1M and 1000 to 1K on javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert 1000000 to 1M also for 1000 To 1K

Any ideas?

I need it for my special project

Comment: Change 1024 to 1000 if you want powers of 10 instead of 2

Comment: I need a function

Comment: And also i dont want convert sizes, I want to convert numbers

Comment: Err... the answer in the dupe is a function and is easily converted to do what you want to do.  Try putting in a bit of effort yourself

Comment: IM NEW TO JAVASCRIPT AND I DONT KNOW HOW TO MAKE THAT, IF I KNOW HOW TO DO IT WHY WOULD I ASK HERE?

Comment: Welcome to SO: No need to shout. If you are clueless and cannot convert the given function from 1024 to 1000, then you need https://www.upwork.com/ and not StackOverflow. In the answer in the dupe, change `var k = 1024,` to `var k = 1000,`

Answer (score 6):

You need to do the conversion from highest to lowest.

```js
function convert(value)
{
    if(value>=1000000)
    {
        value=(value/1000000)+"M"
    }
    else if(value>=1000)
    {
        value=(value/1000)+"K";
    }
    return value;
}
console.log(convert(1000));
console.log(convert(10000));
console.log(convert(300000));
console.log(convert(3000000));
```

Comment: Is there for B?

Comment: You can add it by yourself right ? Add before M. Divide by 1000000000!